# How to generate application secret key for PlayFramework project?

Tags: playframework

I don't understand how to generate an application secret key for my project.

Where should I run `playGenerateSecret` command?

Comment: Please first read the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ApplicationSecret#generating-an-application-secret

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear, you need to run `playGenerateSecret` inside an [sbt shell session](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Interactive-Mode.html). So you first run `sbt` command (or `sbt shell`) and then `playGenerateSecret`. The point about using sbt shell is that you won't need to start it for every command you need to run, but instead, you can reuse the same sbt session.

You can also just run `sbt playGenerateSecret`.